# Why is 2000 grit good enough for a mirror finish?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

The mean particles size on a 2000 grit sandpaper is ~ 1 um, which is not that smooth compared with the wavelength of visible light. But usually when I want a mirror finish, 2000 grit will provide a satisfactory result. Why is that?

Also, is there any simple computational model regarding light reflection that a layman can try out on his own computer? Thanks!

Comment: 2000 grit is not 1 um, it's 10 um. It is not satisfactory for mirror finish. We usually polish stuff down to 2000 grit, then start polishing with diamond paste down to 0.25 um. Then you can really see a beautiful mirror finish.

Comment: @JohnForkosh Well it must've been a really long time ago! Actually 2000 is finer than 100/50.  When I want a mirror surface I'd usually go from 400, then 800, 1200, 1500, and finally 2000 (or skip a few steps in the middle if I'm feeling lazy).

Comment: @Michael I've only worked with stainless steel. 2000 grit don't look too great but there won't be any noticeable scratches. So maybe it's not technically a mirror surface, but I could see my reflection through it, which still baffles me as when I look at the numbers I don't think it's smooth enough.

Comment: 2000 grit is $1.2 \mu$m according to this website http://www.washingtonmills.com/guides/grit-sizes-fepa/particle-size-conversion-chart-fepa/ That being the case it is unlikely that you will be able to **see** the scratches in the surface with the naked eye and so the surface looks polished although not so in terms of the requirements of a telescope objective.

Comment: @arax https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandpaper#Grit_sizes according to this there are two ways of defining grit. One fits mine, another fits yours. Anyway, as someone who just polished iron today (not steel, but close enough), it becomes shiny and reflective at 10 um. True mirror polish is only achieved at 1 and preferably below that.

Comment: There may be a misunderstanding here. Carbides with grit sizes are used for grinding, not polishing, which is done with much softer oxides or red rouge. You can never achieve a scratch free surface with carbides alone and unless you have a cleanroom and extremely clean grinding conditions and compounds, there will always be visible scratches on optical surfaces. For many applications this may not matter, but if you need optics for the detection of faint objects, then it does.

Comment: @Michael My sandpaper says "#2000" not "P2000" so it probably goes by the CAMI designation.